# why does compiler "allows" static function which takes dynamic parameter to be called in the instance's context?

Tags: c#, .net

probably I'm missing something but I have no idea why does compiler allows this call for static function `Foo`:

```
this.Foo(this.ViewBag);
```

Here is the complete code (Visual Studio 2012, brand new MVC4 project):

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        this.Foo(this.ViewBag);     // will compile
        this.Foo(new object());     // will NOT compile
        this.Bar(this.ViewBag);     // will compile
        this.Bar(new object());     // will NOT compile
        return View();
    }

    internal static void Bar(object viewBag)
    {

    }

    internal static void Foo(dynamic viewBag)
    {

    }
}
```

Of course at run time I get

> Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: Member
>   'HomeController.Foo(object)' cannot be accessed with an instance
>   reference; qualify it with a type name instead

is it my "bug" (most likely I don't know something about `dynamic` keyword), or compiler's bug?

Comment: I'm confused why either would compile, what with using `this` to access a static method.

Comment: Yeah, I just tested this. I'm pretty sure this won't compile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you use `dynamic` anywhere in an expression, the entire expression is bound at runtime.
Therefore, the compiler won't even catch "obvious" mistakes like that one.

Comment: Ah, got it. This makes sense now.

Comment: thanks! But why? where can I read more about this? I mean, I understand that some parts of the expression MUST be bound at runtime - but why does access rules are not being checked at compile time? I can't think of any counter-example where that would be decided at runtime instead of compile time - can you?

Comment: @avs099: Since the compiler doesn't know the parameter type, there is a very limited amount of validation it can do, and it would probably involve lots of code duplication in the compiler.

Comment: @avs099: For example, what if there is both a static and an instance method with the same name?